# For loops and multiple conditions

Tags: python, loops, conditional-statements

In C++, it's possible to say:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100 && !found; i++) {
  if (items[i] == "the one I'm looking for")
    found = true;
}
```

so you don't need to use the "break" statement.

In Python, I guess you need to write:

```
found = False

for item in items:
    if item == "the one I'm looking for"
        found = True
        break
```

I know that I can write a generator which has the same code in it so I can hide this break thing. But I wonder if there is any other way to implement the same thing (with the same performance) without using extra variables or while loop.

I know we can say:

```
found = "the one I'm looking for" in items
```

I'm just trying to learn if it's possible to use multiple conditions in for loops.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's posible to say what you just said in C++, but I guarantee you that it doesn't do what you intended—the comma operator evaluate its left-hand argument (which has no side effects here) and then evaluates its right-hand argument and results in that value.

Comment: The C++ should really be: `for (int i = 0; i < 100 && !found; ++i)`

Comment: This depends on what you want to happen if the item isn't found.

Comment: @Adam But it still breaks the loop without iterating through all the items. That's what I'm looking for in Python. I'm looking for an alternative for not to use a break statement.

Comment: @pocoa: do you have a particular use in mind? `break` is often cleaner, as you don't need to structure the loop body so the rest of it won't be executed when you stop the loop early. Also, not using `break` results in a more complex condition in the C++ `for` and Python `while` loops.

Comment: @outis I think it's much more cleaner since you don't need to read the code inside the loop and see where the break is. Without using break you can see the loop condition on the first line.

Comment: @pocoa: I see what you're getting at. My response is it may be somewhat more readable in some cases, but in general you still would need to read the loop body to see when the condition would be false (i.e. to see when the variables in the condition statement are set to values that would cause the condition to fail).

Comment: @outis I agree, but it's still nice if you can decrease these cases.

Comment: @pocoa: of course, in C++ you would not use a `for` loop. You would use: `bool found = std::find(items, items + 100, "the one") != items + 100;` (C++03) or `bool found = std::any_of(std::begin(items), std::end(items), [](std::string const& s) { return s == "the one"});` (C++0x), the latter allowing arbitrary conditions.

Comment: @Matthieu I know, it is just an example to compare the for loops in Python and C++. It's not about finding an item into a loop, it could be something much more complicated. So, finding an item into a list is not the case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> from itertools import dropwhile
>>> try:
...     item = next(dropwhile(lambda x: x!="the one I'm looking for", items))
...     found = True
... except:
...     found = False
```

Of course you can also write this without the lambda function as

```
>>> from itertools import dropwhile
>>> try:
...     item = next(dropwhile("the one I'm looking for".__ne__, items))
...     found = True
... except:
...     found = False
```

Now it looks to me that it is the C version using extra variables

If you really just need the found variable set (and don't need to know the item), then simply use

```
found = any(item=="the one I'm looking for" for item in items)
```

Comment: Ah! The latter is really neat.

Comment: @gnibber I could learn something new from your post, so I'll accept your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Since [`for` loops](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) in Python iterate over a sequence rather than a condition and a mutation statement, the `break` is necessary to bail out early. In other words, `for` in python isn't a conditional loop. The Python equivalent to C++'s `for` would be a [`while` loop](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#while).

```
i=0
found=False
while i < 100 and !found:
    if items[i] == "the one I'm looking for":
        found=True
    i += 1
```

Even in C++, [`for` loops can be rewritten as `while` loops](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/open/n2356/stmt.html#stmt.for) if they don't contain a `continue` statement.

```
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 100 && !found) {
        if (items[i] == "the one I'm looking for")
            found = true;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, somebody should write a PEP for this feature :)

Comment: `for` in Python is like `foreach` in c# and is completely different than the `for` in C, C++ or Java.

Comment: @Richard Yeah, but would be nice to have that feature.

Comment: @outis Yeah, it's the other way to do it. But now you have an "i" variable outside of the loop. Seems like it's not possible in Python.

Comment: @pocoa: a PEP for a C-like `for` would likely get voted down as being unpythonic.

Comment: @outis :)) Why? You didn't see my PEP yet :) What about "for item in items if not found"

Comment: @pocoa: actually, that syntax is rather nice. The reason I called it "unpythonic" is that `break` serves the same purpose, and any C-like conditions on `for` loops would add needless complexity to those loops.

Comment: @outis What about this statement in Python "for item in [item.lower() for item in items]". That is more complicated than my example but still exists in Python.

Comment: @pocoa: it's not that conditions on `for` loops would allow for more complex loop bodies, it's that it would require them. Any syntax feature could be used in a complex statement. That doesn't mean the feature itself adds complexity.

Comment: @pocoa: NO, that's not a nice feature. The C syntax will *stop* once the condition is reached, which makes it useful. The Python syntax wouldn't. The C for loop is essentially just a while loop, the Python for loop is something completely different. Your proposal therefore doesn't make any sense, really.

Comment: @Lennart Thanks for your post. Well, I don't understand why you're saying it doesn't make sense. I know that the for loops in Python are actually generators. I wouldn't ask this question if I wouldn't know that. I said it would be nice to have a similar feature in Python. There's no need to be conservative about that. Python is still evolving.C++ is not my favorite language, I said that I like that feature which lets you to define multiple conditions into the for loop definition, that's all. It's not very nice to say "doesn't make sense" btw. Even Guido wouldn't say that.

Comment: @pocoa: No, the for loops are not generators. You are thinking of generator expressions, which also use the keyword "for". The "for x in blah:" statement is not a generator, it takes a generator as argument. In C, the for loop is actually a while loop. In Python it is NOT. It's not a question of being conservative. The for loop in Python just doesn't work anything like the C++ one does. Completely different things. They just happen to use the same word; "for". Btw, I've heard Guido say exactly "That doesn't make sense" when somebody proposed a feature that didn't make sense. ;)

Comment: @Lennart I think it's still possible to be knowledgeable and kind.

Comment: @pocoa: And you would be right. And I don't think it's unkind to say that it doesn't make any sense, when it doesn't make any sense. In C the condition in the for loop will break a loop. In Python it wouldn't do that. Such a condition in Python would be pretty useless.

Comment: @pocoa: Lennart may be being unkind to your idea, but he isn't trying to criticize you. You are certainly making sense, in that we understand you. If you meet an idea on the road, kill it.

Comment: Why `!found` and not `not found`?

Comment: @outis Thanks. I can understand the opposition. But it doesn't matter what the other people say about that, as a programmer, I'm feeling the need of that feature. So with all my respect to those opposite arguments, they could not convince me at all. Just saying "doesn't makes sense" is not enough to support an argument.

Answer (score 2):

`if` isn't the only statement to get an `else` clause in Python:

```
for item in items:
  if item == "the one I'm looking for":
    break
else:
  print "Item not found! Run away! Run away!"
  return
do_something_with(item)
```

`while` and `try` also have `else` clauses.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not my question :)

Comment: @Ignacio: As of now, indentation of `else` doesn't match that of `if`.

Comment: @pocoa: Sometimes Python forces you to think different. This is what confuses programmers coming from other languages.

Comment: @Nawaz: Of course not. It matches the `for`. Which is on purpose.

Comment: @Ignacio: Oooo... I didn't know that. What is the idea? What does it do? (I'm not a python programmer btw, so forgive my ignorance, I had written few codes when I was in college).

Comment: @Ignacio Yeah, I love everything about Python. Would be nice to have that feature though :)

Comment: @pocoa, Your question asks about how to translate C idioms into Python. The point here is that in real Python the likes of the `found` variable are not needed so often because the looping constructs are similar but different to C (and other languages). The differences _are_ important to learn about unless you are happy to churn out crappy Python code

Comment: @Nawaz: If `break` is *not* executed in a `for` or `while` loop then the `else` clause will executed.

Comment: @gnibbler No, my question is "... I wonder if there is any other way to implement the same thing (with the same performance) without using extra variables or while loop."

Comment: @pocoa: The simple answer is "no". The more complex answer is "you don't need to".

Comment: @Ignacio: Ooo...that's very nice feature. Thanks for teaching me this. :-) +1.

Comment: @Ignacio Yes, that's what I was asking for. Of course you can write in different the same thing in many different ways but that's something would be nice to have. At least I would like to have that.

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```
def search(match, items):
    for item in items:
        if item == match:
            return True
    return False
```

EDIT:

```
def search(match, test, items):
    for item in items:
        if item == match and test(item) and the_sky_is_not_falling:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Yeah, but that's not what I'm asking for. I'm just trying to understand if Python supports multiple conditions in for loops.

Comment: Python doesn't support conditions in `for` at all. `for` doesn't handle conditions.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes you can!**

```
>>> found = False
>>> for x in (x for x in range(10) if not found):
...    print x
...    if x == 5:
...       print "Found!"
...       found = True
... 
0
1
2
3
4
5
Found!
```

But it's daft, as you continue the loop even after x is found, so don't do it. :-)